# Not able to understand use of NS runloop

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile

I am using [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html) class supplied by apple in my pinging application. I have scratched my head 100 times but I am unable to get the logic of using of line:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

in main.m file, line no:169.

Whats the use of that line? Why do we need to run this line until self.ping gets nil.
I am beginner, so please bear with me. I have spend almost 5 hrs studying run loops, ns timers but nothing is going in my head.

Answer (score 0):

sI still didn't had time to take a look at the code, but usually it is used to keep a runloop alive. The main thread is always kept alive, but if you create another thread with some sort of async operation it will be dead as soon as it starts to receive callbacks, in this way you keep the thread alive. For example: let's say that you want to manage all the async download operations on another thread, NSURLConnection class provides async callbacks based on delegation pattern. If you spawn your connection on another thread as soon as it reaches the end of the method the thread will be closed and there is no opportunity to receive those callbacks. Keeping this thread alive everything will work.

Comment: but why do we need to run this line of code indefinately as done in this code. To try my point I deleted the do-while loop and called this LOC only one time. It didnt workred. I than ran it two times. It started working. So, running this LOC more than one times make this logic work but it doesnt work if I run this once . Why this behaviour? and if its working for running the loop two times than why the author has ran it infinite times ?

Comment: Also, only thread running in this example is main thread. So, why we need to run  NSrunloop

Comment: As i said i didn't watch the code, but probably is not an iOS application but just an objective c sample. In this case you should keep alive the main too of the re is and kind of asynchronous operation. You should think that maybe se are not at the same GMT